# get old values of connectionstring from app.config

Tags: c#, configuration, connection-string, oledb, app-config

I have an existing connectionString in my app.config and I want to read all the properties. The connection string is something like below

```
<add name="Toast" connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Password=abc@123;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Toast;Data Source=192.168.29.232"/>
```

While this is an [OleDB connectionstring](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) the OleDBConnection class does not provide all the properties. For eg; if I want to read InitialCatalog OleDBConnection object does not have a property for it.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["Toast"].ToString());
string db = connection.Database;
string provider = connection.Provider;
string datasrc = connection.DataSource;
```

Which class object will give me all the property values of this connectionString?

I think this is an oleDB connectionstring because of this link 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Comment: Maybe something like `DbConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: Actually, initial catalog is `connection.Database`...

Comment: DbConnectionStringBuilder can give me an ICollection of the key and values separately but again I will have to loop through everything also though it looks straight forward to find the same index for the key and value collection but again not as simple as using object.properties.

Comment: @Fabjan: you are right, what about other properties though? Like username, and persist security info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database is Initial Catalog.

This should clear the air.

[image]

Comment: what about other properties like username and security info?

Comment: You can do `var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(str); var user = builder["User Id"];`

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Agrawal - using the keys as indexes helped.